# How to replace a text in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column which looks like

```
Quarter
-------
Q1 2012
Q2 2012
Q1 2013
```

and I want

```
Quarter
-------
Q1
Q2
Q1
```

Here's what I've come with:

```
UPDATE TABLE [WA Products Sales].[dbo].[WA_Sales_Products]
SET 
    Quarter = REPLACE (Quarter, SUBSTRING(Quarter, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Quarter)-1)
```

Which returns

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: there's definetly missing a closing bracket, but if this is the problem...

Comment: Nope, I just didn't select it while copying the syntax. But thanks.

Comment: MS is not my dialect... are you sure the `TABLE` keyword is needed? Are the brackets [] correct?

Comment: Replace takes  3 Arguments, why not simply `Quarter = SUBSTRING(Quarter, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Quarter)-1)`

Comment: It works without TABLE.
`Quarter = SUBSTRING(Quarter, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Quarter)-1)` produces
`Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this query:

```
UPDATE TABLE [WA Products Sales].[dbo].[WA_Sales_Products]
    SET Quarter = REPLACE(Quarter, SUBSTRING(Quarter, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Quarter)-1)
```

is that it fails when `Quarter` does not have a space.  A more minor problem is that `LEFT()` is more appropriate.  You can fix the first problem by adding in a space:

```
UPDATE TABLE [WA Products Sales].[dbo].[WA_Sales_Products]
    SET Quarter = LEFT(Quarter, CHARINDEX(' ', Quarter + ' ') - 1);
```

This should fix the issue with a bad argument to `LEFT()`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, this should get you the desired results:

```
UPDATE [WA Products Sales].[dbo].[WA_Sales_Products]
SQL Quarter = LEFT(Quarter, 2)
WHERE LEN(Quarter) > 1 -- added this condition
```

Comment: `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`
But I wanted to make it more universal.

Comment: It's odd, because this works fine:
`ALTER TABLE [WA Products Sales].[dbo].[WA_Sales_Products]
ADD Q AS LEFT (Quarter, charindex(' ', Quarter)-1)`

Comment: See my edited answer. Added a where condition so that the update will only take place on values longer then one char. This should prevent the error you reported.

Comment: `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.` This is beginning to be a kind of frustrating...

Comment: Thanks, it seems the syntax you provided is correct. I'm getting the same error whatever syntax I write, even SELECT TOP(100) * FROM ... produce `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.` now. It looks like some problem in Management Studio, but it persist even after restart.

Comment: Since mine database is not huge, I decided to choose different approach through Excel in order to accomplish this task.